# Write to a file from Windows Explorer extension with UAC dialog

Tags: c++, windows, uac, windows-explorer

I need to copy a virtual file from my Windows Explorer namespace extension to a restricted location (for example to C:). Normally for such task one need to run a new process elevated that should do the operation.

However in this case I'm running in explorer.exe process context, and I need to get the same `"You'll need to provide administrator permission to copy..."` dialog that Windows Explorer presents, rather than a UAC dialog for a new process.

Anyone knows what function Windows Explorer uses to achieve this? ShFileOperation does what I need, but seems to work only for file system objects. How Windows Explorer copies files from zip archives which are represented via namespsace extensions too? Thank you

[image]

Comment: Like it says in the first line of the `SHFileOperation` documentation: Try `IFileOperation`.